# make permutations impossible to insert db2

Tags: sql, database, insert, db2

I would love to have some help with a small problem I have.
Suppose I have a table called table0 with two columns, c and d.
Suppose I do an insert such as 'insert into table0 values ('paco', sono')

How do I make this table so that I CANNOT do an 'insert into table0 values ('sono','paco')?
In other words, assuming this table has already a unique key defined on columns c and d, how do you further constraint the table to not allow permuations?

I already tried 'alter table table0 add constraint new unique(d,c)' but this doesn't work

Comment: Hint: write trigger at inserting to stop it.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
CREATE TRIGGER table0 
NO CASCADE BEFORE INSERT ON table0 
REFERENCING NEW AS Newrow
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
WHEN (Newrow.C IN (SELECT D FROM table0) OR Newrow.D IN (SELECT C FROM table0)) 
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '70001' ('Duplicate Exists');
```